# Spring 4: Inject field on runtime object creation

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I am struggling with following problem in **Spring**:

I have a very basic class like this:

```
public class DefaultPropertiesLoader {

    private Properties _defaultProperties;

    public DefaultPropertiesLoader() {}

    public Properties getDefaultProperties() {
        return _defaultProperties;
    }

    public void setDefaultProperties(Properties defaultProperties) {
        _defaultProperties = defaultProperties;
    }
}
```

and I want the `_defaultProperties` field to be injected from Spring bean when creating `DefaultPropertiesLoader` on runtime, for example:

```
DefaultPropertiesLoader loader = new DefaultPropertiesLoader();
Properties props = loader.getDefaultProperties();
```

The problem is `_defaultProperties` field is not injected and stays equal to **`null`**.

Here is a snippet of beans definition in Spring configuration file:

```
<bean class="eu.biosdesign.trading.platform.service.DefaultPropertiesLoader">
    <property name="defaultProperties" ref="defaultSettings"/>
</bean>

<bean id="defaultSettings" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
    <property name="location" value="classpath:default.properties"/>
</bean>
```

Is this a normal behaviour or am I doing something wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You wrote `new DefaultPropertiesLoader();` and later invoked the method `getDefaultProperties()`? Where is Spring involved in all this?

Comment: It's just a small example. I am trying to achieve injection of `_defaultProperties` when creating new object on runtime.

Comment: Then look at `@Configurable`.

Comment: Thanks, that might be what I am looking for.